# Property in C# windows phone

Tags: c#, get, set

I have one question about how to get and set in c #

I enter data in Page1 through Class1 and appears in Page2 but unachievable set values in Page1.

Page1

```
namespace textMuc
{
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 cl = new Class1();
        cl.Muc = 123;
    }
}
```

Page2

```
namespace textMuc
{
public partial class Page2 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Class1 cl = new Class1();

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txthien.Text = cl.Muc.ToString();
    }

}
```

}
Class1

```
namespace textMuc
{
public class Class1
{
    private int capdo = 100;
    public int Muc
    {
        get { return capdo; }
        set { capdo = value; }
    }
}
```

}
What should I do?
Thank!!!

Comment: Have you tried reading a c# tutorial/book?

Comment: sorry I've been learning c # but I do not know about c #

Comment: I guess you want to pass cl from Page1 to Page2, you will need to make that static in Page1 or send it to Page2 and storing it statically in Page2

Comment: Thanks it worked!!!!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found your problem with static

```
namespace textMuc
{
public class Class1
{
    private static int capdo = 100;
    public int Muc
    {
        get { return capdo; }
        set { capdo = value; }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the capdo variable static...

```
namespace textMuc
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private static int capdo = 100;
        public int Muc
        {
            get { return capdo; }
            set { capdo = value; }
        }
    }
}
```